# What is the reason these two UV maps interfere with each other?

Tags: materials, uv

The selected face shouldn't be painted with the text "*This*" from the third texture of the material (see in Property region on the right):

[image]

There are two UV maps used for the cube mesh, one for the full cube (6 faces), one for the top face alone. The material includes three textures, the two first ones (background colors and white dots) are to be used with the full cube UV map visible in the middle panel, the last one is the text, also visible in the middle panel. Its map is the large square around it.

The selected face, and the other faces except the blue one, keep receiving the portion of the circular text they would receive with the full cube map. What's wrong?

Using Blender Internal (2.79).
File is available [here](https://nofile.io/f/WOkhbrdxbA1/cube_texture.blend).

Comment: Does that happen even at render mode? Also, please show us the list of UV maps.

Comment: @Allosteric: It's the same on the rendered image. UV maps visible on this [second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05JTU.png).

Comment: I tried a similar setting and didn't reproduce. Why not upload your .blend if you don't mind.

Comment: @Allosteric: I added a link at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `UVMap Face 1` is actually mapping the `Face 1.png`

1. In your list of UV Maps, select the UVMap Face 1.
2. In the 3D view, select all the faces except the dice face 1.
3. In the UV/Image editor, press <kbd>W</kbd> twice (Weld) and move the dot to some where safe(transparent)

That'll resolve your problem.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This works as intended, thanks. However I don't understand why `UVMap Face 1` was created with coordinates for other faces, as I think I selected face 1 only before unwrapping. I expected the UV map would only contain selected vertices, as explained [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html): "*Begin by selecting all faces to be unwrapped in the 3D View*"). It's very confusing, and I don't get a correct understanding of how UV maps are used by Blender.

Comment: @mins I'm not quite sure, but I think any new made UV map will copy a previous UV map. As far as I observed, the very first UV map is weld in the left corner (by default) but the subsequent maps mimic the previous ones